# transforming it into a heat equation (how I write down the solution)

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

$u_t + a\cdot\bigtriangledown u + bu = \Delta u $
$ u(x,0) = f(x) $.

$a$ and $b$ are constants...
I wish to write down explicit formula for a solution.
I tried to make some change of variables to get a heat equation. But I couldn't solve the question!

I appreciate any help.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try
$$
v(x,t)=e^{bt}u(x+t\,a,t).
$$

Comment: I think this question is interesting, could you please show me how to take derivative of t plz? esp the $u(x+ta,t)$ part, should I take the total derivative?

Comment: $$v_t=be^{bt}u+e^{bt}\(\sum_{i=1}^na_iu_{x_i}+u_t\)$$